# Yii booster CKeditor widget replace the enterMode

Tags: php, yii, widget, ckeditor4.x, yii-booster

I need help here. I have a system developed with Yii framework. I have the CKEDITOR widget in Yii Booster. When user press the enter key, I want to have '**br**'instead of '**p**'.

Below is my script:

```
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbCKEditor',array(
    'model'=>$model,           
    'attribute'=>'qualifications', 
    'editorOptions'=>array(
                    'enterMode'=> 'CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR',
                    ),
) );
```

However, when I run the script, it still gives me **p** instead of **br**. I have been looking for the solution for few days. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

you can have solution from here https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/issues/41

you need to use `clientOptions` like below:

```
$form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'standard',
        'clientOptions'=>[
            'enterMode' => 2,
            'forceEnterMode'=>false,
            'shiftEnterMode'=>1
        ]
    ])
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, because my form was created in Yii Booster, is there another way to solve this by using booster instead?

Comment: I think I solve it! Thanks so much Albert. I actually just need to change the enterMode option to 2. Thanks for your reference. It is a big help for me!

Comment: wc!. just accept answer and upvote it so user will get help if will have same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this post:

```
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbCKEditor',array(
    'model'=>$model,           
    'attribute'=>'qualifications', 
    'editorOptions'=>array(
                    'enterMode'=> 2,
                    ),
) );
```